# One network interface with 2 gateways

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have 2 routers connected via ethernet cable. The secondary router has it's DHCP server disabled and has an IP address of 192.168.1.2. Both routers have different internet. If I create another default gateway with lower metric then I can use the second network as the primary network.

`ip route add default via 192.168.1.2 dev eno1 metric 10`

It works as expected.

Now I'm trying to use both networks simultaneously. Is it possible to create a linux user and send all the user traffic through the secondary gateway? I tried the following commands:

```
useradd kreator
ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42
ip route add default via 192.168.1.2 dev eno1 table 42 metric 200
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner kreator -j MARK --set-mark 42
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -m mark --mark 42 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2
```

Then I ran `sudo -u kreator ping google.com` and it didn't log anything. What am I missing?

I'm on Arch linux and network manager is NetworkManager daemon.

Comment: My understanding of policy-based routing is limited, but... what's the idea behind adjusting the `POSTROUTING` chain? By the looks of things, doing that `SNAT` piece will cause the secondary router, `192.168.1.2`, to get packets from your host with a source IP of... itself (`192.168.1.2`), which might be throwing the secondary router off. My gut tells me that you don't need the last `POSTROUTING` bit. Once the `OUTPUT` chain has `MARK`ed the packet, the routing table should see that and use table 42 for its routing decision rather than the `main` table.

Comment: @PrestonManess You are right. I didn't need the `POSTROUTING` policy. I tried without that and it's working now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, the approach was solid:

1. Instruct the OS to look at table 42 for routing decisions on any packet with a `fwmark` of 42: `ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42`
2. Add the alternative default route to that table: `ip route add default via 192.168.1.2 dev eno1 table 42 metric 200`
3. Mark (in the `mangle` table) all outbound packets (in the `OUTPUT` chain) originating from a process owned by user `kreator` with `42`: `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner kreator -j MARK --set-mark 42`

At this point, packets originating from user `kreator` get marked and routed by the alternative default route in table 42, as desired. The extra `iptables` command adjusting the `POSTROUTING` chain was erroneous, as it was changing the source IP to that of the secondary router, and likely causing the router to drop the packet.